# Need recommendation for Websphere tutorial

Tags: java, websphere

Coming from Apache-Tomcat background, I need to do some work with Websphere (v7). Must say I am blown away by the jargon in the Help section - a "New Project" gives me 17 options and I don't know what they mean; the "Hello World" tutorial makes me create some objects and structures that I dont know how to use (What is mediation, and how does it help me write the client?).

An example problem: I want to create a simple web service - that can be called with or without a word as an argument. Without the argument, a list or words is sent back, and with a word from that list as an argument, its meaning. Word not in list - error message goes out.

Where do I start? I wrote the wsdl, could write the class file as a servlet too, but I'd like to do it the Websphere way, using Eclipse/JUnit for development/testing. Can anybody recommend a tutorial that explains the steps of doing something similar (in terms of simplicity)? I want to learn the EAR file structures, location and contents of scripts if they are used (e.g., ant), how/when dependencies are translated and the Xml marshalled, at what level Exceptions are handled, best logging practices, where the configuration files are and what can be configured, etc.

It's OK if the tutorial doesn't cover all of the above, I just need a good starting point, and material that I can read and understand. Don't need the layers/tiers of business models or DB access, just something simple to get my hands dirty. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM Education Assistant](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/topic/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/plugin_coverpage.html) might provide a good starting point, depending on what exactly you want to learn.
Alternatively, I would suggest to search [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/newto/)
.